# Can i write multiple logic operators in c++

Tags: c++, logic

```
int main()
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
cin>>a>>b>>c;
}
{
if (a==b || b==c || a==c)
{
cout<<"dulicate exist";
```

in this code i have used two **OR**|| || (logical operations ) in a  single statement . is this allowed in c++ syntax

Comment: yes. However your code is incorrect ( "{" at the wrong place)

Comment: @Hassaan Why not just try it? and use debugger to step through the code! If never heard of a debugger, just give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Yes using multiple expressions separated by logical or or and in a condition is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use multiple logic operators. Next time, compile the code and see if it gives any errors. If not, it is allowed.

Comment: This *may* not always be a valid test.  A source file can contain compiler or platform specific functionality that may not be acceptable to other compilers or platforms.